# update data with href link in django and ajax

Tags: django

```
$("#feedlikes").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url:'{% url "feedlikes" %}',
            data:{},
            success: function({
                alert("Updated Successfully")
            }),
        }),
    }),
```

**those are my Ajax code help me to get them work.**
**this is my view:**

```
def feedlikes(request, feed_id):
    feed_update= Feeds.objects.get(pk=feed_id)
    feed_update.likes = feed_update.likes +1
    feed_update.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your feedlikes function expect feed_id but you are not supplying in the ajax url. Your ajax url should be

```
url:'{% url "feedlikes" feed_id=1 %}'
```

The problem: how to get that feed id in ajax?

You can make a hidden html tag  with id equal to #feedlikes-id (eg feedlikes-1) inside #feedlike div or something like that and access just above submitting ajax and store in some variable and set to url then submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the data you need to pass `post` method in ajax with csrf_token in headers.

```
$("#feedlikes").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url:'{% url "feedlikes" %}',
            data:{},
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': {{csrf_token}}
            },
            success: function({
                alert("Updated Successfully")
            }),
        }),
    }),
```